# Locally Spring Boot integration tests passed, but on bamboo all test fail

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, bamboo, spring-boot-test

Have some Spring Boot Integrationtests, e.g.:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SupplierToSapInvoiceIntegrationTest {
    ...
}
```

All tests are successful when running locally, but on bamboo all tests fail. The Log says:

> build 05-Mai-2017 15:20:46        2017-05-05 15:20:46.943  INFO 6556 ---
>   [    Test worker] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Neither
>   @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class
>   [com.odm.integration.SupplierToSapIntegrationTest], using
>   SpringBootContextLoader build 05-Mai-2017 15:20:46        2017-05-05
>   15:20:46.943  INFO 6556 --- [    Test worker]
>   o.s.t.c.support.AbstractContextLoader    : Could not detect default
>   resource locations for test class
>   [com.odm.integration.SupplierToSapIntegrationTest]: no resource found
>   for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}. build    05-Mai-2017
>   15:20:46      2017-05-05 15:20:46.943  INFO 6556 --- [    Test worker]
>   t.c.s.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils : Could not detect default
>   configuration classes for test class
>   [com.odm.integration.SupplierToSapIntegrationTest]:
>   SupplierToSapIntegrationTest does not declare any static, non-private,
>   non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
>   build 05-Mai-2017 15:20:46        2017-05-05 15:20:46.943  INFO 6556 ---
>   [    Test worker] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Found
>   @SpringBootConfiguration com.odm.OdmBackendApplication for test class
>   com.odm.integration.SupplierToSapIntegrationTest build    05-Mai-2017
>   15:20:46      2017-05-05 15:20:46.943  INFO 6556 --- [    Test worker]
>   .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Loaded default
>   TestExecutionListener class names from location
>   [META-INF/spring.factories]:
>   [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener,
>   org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
>   build 05-Mai-2017 15:20:46        2017-05-05 15:20:46.943  INFO 6556 ---
>   [    Test worker] .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Could not
>   instantiate TestExecutionListener
>   [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener].
>   Specify custom listener classes or make the default listener classes
>   (and their required dependencies) available. Offending class:
>   [javax/servlet/ServletContext] build  05-Mai-2017 15:20:46
>   2017-05-05 15:20:46.943  INFO 6556 --- [    Test worker]
>   .b.t.c.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper : Using
>   TestExecutionListeners:
>   [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@7beec6bf,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@79dadc3e,
>   org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@128f4f9c,
>   org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@dad26fb,
>   org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@fbd2cf,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@2fefc5c2,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@47749c0c,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@230af0e7,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@7db923e3,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@2c293843,
>   org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@4f5e5536]

Any idea, help? THX!!